# Error related to setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, loops, sequence

I am a beginner with Python and I will be thankful if someone helps me with the following error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I want the program takes the related values from the array `Ir` at each step and runs it in the loop. I mean it should take `Ir[0]=0 , Ir[1]=200 ,...` and calculates the corresponding `I[0], I[1], ...`

```
 from math import *
from pylab import *
from numpy import *
from scipy import *
Ir=arange(200,1201,200)
Temp=25.0
Area=243.36
Isc_cell = 9.01984039
ns=1
np=1
V = arange(0,0.7,0.01)
n1=1.0
Is1 = 1.5648048e-10
n2= 2.0
Is2= 9.85608e-6
T_co = 0.0005
Rs = 2.7487398e-3
Rsh = 410913.8725
k = 1.38e-23
q = 1.6e-19
Eg=1.11
T= Temp+273.0
Tmeas= 273+25.0
Vt=(k*T)/q

j=range(0,6)
Iph=zeros(6)
I=zeros(6)
#I=zeros(len(V))
I0=Is1*((T/Tmeas)**(3/n1))*exp(Eg*((T/Tmeas)-1)/(n1*Vt));
I02=Is2*((T/Tmeas)**(3/n2))*exp(Eg*((T/Tmeas)-1)/(n2*Vt));
for i in j:
    Iph[i] = Isc_cell*(Ir[i]/1000.0)*(1+(T_co*(Temp-25)));
    I[i] = Iph[i] - I0*(exp((V+I[i]*Rs)/(n1*Vt))-1)-I02*(exp((V+I[i]*Rs)/(n2*Vt))-1)-((V+I[i]*Rs)/Rsh);
    i=i+1
```

P.s. I am confused since it works for `Iph[i]` but it has an error for `I[i]`.

Comment: The problem is, that `I=zeros(6)` expects you to save floats in `I`, but when you assign `I[i]` the result of the right-hand computation is an array, which in turn causes the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because *V* is an array and you forget use the subscript. Replace with this line for I.

```
I[i] = Iph[i] - I0*(exp((V[i]+I[i]*Rs)/(n1*Vt))-1)-I02*(exp((V[i]+I[i]*Rs)/(n2*Vt))-1)-((V[i]+I[i]*Rs)/Rsh)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was the mistake and I have to make it two dimensional for my purpose. sorry that I cannot vote up since my reputations are not enough.